# How to drop column with FluentMigrator?

Tags: c#, migration, .net-4.5, fluent-migrator

I am using `.Net4.5` and `C#`, I am working on one of database migrations [using `FluentMigrator`](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Fluent-Interface). I am able to alter tables and add columns by using

```
Alter.Table("Items").InSchema("Pricing")
            .AddColumn("CanBe").AsBoolean().NotNullable()
```

However I need to drop some existing columns and nor `DeleteColumn` nor `DropColumn` methods are not on `IAlterTableAddColumnOrAlterColumnOrSchemaSyntax` interface.

**How do I drop columns using FluentMigrator?**

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Found it myself:

It has to go as separate statement.

```
Alter.Table("Items").InSchema("Pricing")
        .AddColumn("CanBe").AsBoolean().NotNullable();

Delete.Column("AllowSubscription").FromTable("Items").InSchema("Pricing");
```

Comment: Shame there isn't an option for `.DeleteColumn` within `Alter.Table` :(

Comment: @Caltor Indeed. I think it is due to this being 'translated' into SQL statements.

Comment: What do you do if there's a foreign key?

Comment: @KellenStuart A few year too late, but you just remove the foreign key before doing the changes