# Delete a column using FluentMigrator

Tags: asp.net-core, fluent-migrator

I want to delete a column from a table using FluenMigrator ver.3.2.6.0. I saw that this question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243778/how-to-drop-column-with-fluentmigrator) some years ago but the solution doesn't fit for me because looks like the method for deleting columns doesn't exist anymore:

Delete.Column("ColumnName").FromTable("TableName").InSchema("SchemaName");

So my question how can I do this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the `AutoReversingMigration` interface in the class change it to `Migration`

```
using FluentMigrator;

namespace proyect_name.Migrations.DefaultDB
{
    [Migration(20210412174600)]
    public class CamsDB_20210412_174600_MigrationName : Migration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            Delete.Column("ColumnName").FromTable("TableName").InSchema("dbo");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
}
```